# Bi-directional database syncing for Postgres and Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, synchronization, data-synchronization, database

Let's say I have a local server running and I also have an exactly similar server already running on amazon.

Both server can `CRUD` data to its databases.

```
Note that the servers use both `postgres` and `mongodb`.
```

Now when no one is using the wifi (usually in the night), I would like to sync both `postgres` and `mongodb` databases so that all writes from **each database on server to each database on local** gets properly applied.

I don't want to use Multi-Master because:

1. MongoDB does not support this architecture itself, so perhaps I will need a complex alternative.
2. I want to control when and how much I sync both databases.
3. I do not want to use network bandwidth when others are using the internet.

So can anyone show me right direction.

Also, if you list some tools that solve my problem, it will be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Any of our [Drivers for MongoDB](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/mongodb/) would let you build your own application to push new/updated documents from your cloud-based database to your local database. I'll get a proper answer written up and posted soon.

Answer (score 1):

We have several drivers what would be able to help you with this process. I'm presuming some knowledge of software development and will showcase our ADO.NET Provider for MongoDB, which using the familiar-looking `MongoDBConnection`, `MongoDBCommand`, and `MongoDBDataReader` objects.

First, you'll want to create your connection string for connecting with you cloud MongoDB instance:

```
string connString = "Auth Database=test;Database=test;Password=test;Port=27117;Server=http://clouddbaddress;User=test;Flatten Objects=false";
```

You'll note that we have the Flatten Objects property set to false, this ensures that any JSON/BSON objects contained in the documents will be returned as raw JSON/BSON.

After you create the connection string, you can establish the connection and read data from the database. You'll want to store the returned data in some way that would let you access it easily for future use.

```
List<string> columns = new List<string>();
List<object> values;
List<List<object>> rows = new List<List<object>>();
using (MongoDBConnection conn = new MongoDBConnection(connString))
{


  //create a WHERE clause that will limit the results to newly added documents
  MongoDBCommand cmd = new MongoDBCommand("SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE ...", conn);
  rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  results = 0;

  while (rdr.Read())
  {
    values = new List<object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
    {
      if (results == 0)
        columns.Add(rdr.GetName(i));
      values.Add(rdr.GetValue(i));
    }
    rows.Add(values);
    results++;
  }
}
```

After you've collected all of the data for each of the objects that you want to replicated, you can configure a new connection to your local MongoDB instance and build queries to insert the new documents.

```
connString = "Auth Database=testSync;Database=testSync;Password=testSync;Port=27117;Server=localhost;User=testSync;Flatten Objects=false";
using (MongoDBConnection conn = new MongoDBConnection(connString)) {
  foreach (var row in rows) {
    //code here to create comma-separated strings for the columns
    //  and values to be inserted in a SQL statement

    String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO backup_table (" + column_names + ") VALUES (" + column_values + ")";
    MongoDBCommand cmd = new MongoDBCommand(sqlInsert, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

At this point, you'll have inserted all of the new documents. You could then change your filter (the WHERE clause at the beginning) to filter based on updated date/time and update their corresponding entries in the local MongoDB instance using the UPDATE command.

Things to look out for:

- Be sure that you're properly filtering out new/updated entries.
- Be sure that you're properly interpreting the type of variable so that you properly surround with quotes (or not) when entering the values in the SQL query.

We have a few drivers that might be useful to you. I demonstrated the [ADO.NET Provider](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/mongodb/ado) above, but we also have a [driver for writing apps in Xamarin](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/mongodb/mobile) and a [JDBC driver (for Java)](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/mongodb/jdbc).